# UPSTART services all hang when stopping (stop/waiting)

Tags: server, upstart, services, init.d

I am using Ubuntu 13.10

After an IPL, there are many run once services that hang, they are all in STOP/WAITING status.

Also, if I try to stop any normal service like `apache2`, `mysql`, `vsftp` I get the same results.

They are in upstart and I have used the commands :

```
stop apche2

service apache2 stop

/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
```

All three variations produce the same results, when I type in `initctl list` I get the service is stop/waiting and the process is still going strong.  I see the process running and it works great for new connections.

I am running the stop commands from root.

There are no entries in any of the logs about the stop command or errors for each service.

How to fix this?

Comment: You mean that you type `sudo stop apache2` and you can't return to the terminal to type the next command?

Comment: When I type sudo stop apache2 the apache2 service does not stop, I get a message stop/waiting.   When I check the service with sudo status apache2 I see the same stop/waiting.  The PID is still running and I can still use apache.  This also occurs for all services like vsftpd, mysql...  Basically I have a bunch of services that all states stop/waiting.  If I run service --status-all, many services have a ? on them.  No syslog entries or entries in the upstart logs.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?